# surround set up with digi 003.

Tags: 5.1, surround-sound, digidesign

Hi
Finlay I've bought another dynaudio bm5a and put it in front of me, as my new center monitor, a first step in the changing my stereo room into a 5.1 environment.

I have digi 003, protools 10, and complete production toolkit.
The new center monitor is plugged on out 3, in the digi 003.

Only problem is, i can not find a decent way to calibrate all of my monitors now, because the main volume out knob doesn't effect the output 3, and so its so loud, and i have this wired feeling that i no longer can trust my ears in "knowing" the room, and how it will react on other stages.

does anyone knows how to calibrate (with out an spl meter, and without surround controller) my room, so I'll have my confidence back, and could easily bounce LCR waves to DCP low budget films I'm editing.

thanks a million

n
.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calibrating without and SPL meter is not calibrating...period.

You're a bit out of luck with the 003 in terms of controlling the other outputs, as well. You will definitely need some sort of surround controller; preferably one that has bass management built in. It may seem like a moot point if you don't have a sub-woofer, but you'll need a sub-woofer eventually...and without bass management, the low end of your monitors will be less predictable outside of your room.

The only thing you can do at the moment to control volume level on all three is use an LCR master fader. It doesn't look like the BM5A's have a trim pot (which makes truly calibrating them without some sort of controller practically impossible). So, you'll need to set the monitor knob on the 003 to max (to match the output of the center channel. Then use your master fader to hit your desired SPL.

Comment: A workaround could be to use three mono master faders for outputs L,C,R and insert a mono trim plug on each master fader, setting trim gain based on SPL meter line up... Group the three faders & theres your overall LCR level and always import those master faders to every session.. (never using the stereo LR knob)

Comment: @tim prebble - that could definitely work.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have an iPhone or Android?  If you do you can download a free SPL meter and then group the outputs once you have calibrated the speakers.

The SPL does not need to accurately calibrated it only needs to be consistent.

If you are careful you can also use the 003 to calibrate the speaker levels.

Generate sine waves at different frequencies and then replay them through the loudspeakers separately.  Use the same mic and preamp/channel to record each speaker and then use the Gain in AudioSuite to establish the RMS and peak levels.  With a lot of patience you will be able to match the levels on all three loudspeakers as well as be confident about the frequency range and balance.

Let us know how you get on.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a bunch guys. i really love this place. been so lonley in my studio ( knowledge wise..)

did some research and found this one :

http://www.smproaudio.com/index.php/en/products/monitor-controllers/mpatch-51

bought it from b&h in 400$ instead of this one :

http://spl.info/hardware/monitor-controller/surround-monitor-controller/kurzbeschreibung.html

which cost 900$..

also bought this d-sub cable :(90$)

http://www.sydec.be/App/Content/?ID=a406f87c-6d97-4827-948a-f2160d02647e

to connect the digi 003 to the controller.

thats it. hope it'll sound good.  next stop is - buying another 2 bm5a and hang them behind me.

Is anybody knows if i could use another type of monitors for st. suround?

like these :

http://www.jblpro.com/catalog/General/Product.aspx?PId=277&MId=1

http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/638082-REG/JBL_8320_8320_Compact_Cinema_Surround.html

having 3 dynaudio bm5a as LCR and two JBL for L/R  R/R , is that make any sence at all?

thanks again

n.